# Three JS: Add Zoom function to the Bounding Box (Rect)

Tags: three.js

Here I have created a rect in which it gets zoom in to the mid point of the scene. Here I'm looking to zoom in to the center of the rect (where we select the object) towards the object.

I have an idea to get the center point of the rect and and pass it to the zoom function where I'm struggling in.

Please help me out

Heres the snippet

```js
/**
 * @author HypnosNova / https://www.threejs.org.cn/gallery
 * This is a class to check whether objects are in a selection area in 3D space
 */

THREE.SelectionBox = (function() {

  var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
  var center = new THREE.Vector3();

  function SelectionBox(camera, scene, deep) {

    this.camera = camera;
    this.scene = scene;
    this.startPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.endPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.collection = [];
    this.deep = deep || Number.MAX_VALUE;

  }

  SelectionBox.prototype.select = function(startPoint, endPoint) {

    this.startPoint = startPoint || this.startPoint;
    this.endPoint = endPoint || this.endPoint;
    this.collection = [];

    this.updateFrustum(this.startPoint, this.endPoint);
    this.searchChildInFrustum(frustum, this.scene);

    return this.collection;

  };

  SelectionBox.prototype.updateFrustum = function(startPoint, endPoint) {

    startPoint = startPoint || this.startPoint;
    endPoint = endPoint || this.endPoint;

    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();

    var tmpPoint = startPoint.clone();
    tmpPoint.x = Math.min(startPoint.x, endPoint.x);
    tmpPoint.y = Math.max(startPoint.y, endPoint.y);
    endPoint.x = Math.max(startPoint.x, endPoint.x);
    endPoint.y = Math.min(startPoint.y, endPoint.y);

    var vecNear = this.camera.position.clone();
    var vecTopLeft = tmpPoint.clone();
    var vecTopRight = new THREE.Vector3(endPoint.x, tmpPoint.y, 0);
    var vecDownRight = endPoint.clone();
    var vecDownLeft = new THREE.Vector3(tmpPoint.x, endPoint.y, 0);
    vecTopLeft.unproject(this.camera);
    vecTopRight.unproject(this.camera);
    vecDownRight.unproject(this.camera);
    vecDownLeft.unproject(this.camera);

    var vectemp1 = vecTopLeft.clone().sub(vecNear);
    var vectemp2 = vecTopRight.clone().sub(vecNear);
    var vectemp3 = vecDownRight.clone().sub(vecNear);
    vectemp1.normalize();
    vectemp2.normalize();
    vectemp3.normalize();

    vectemp1.multiplyScalar(this.deep);
    vectemp2.multiplyScalar(this.deep);
    vectemp3.multiplyScalar(this.deep);
    vectemp1.add(vecNear);
    vectemp2.add(vecNear);
    vectemp3.add(vecNear);

    var planes = frustum.planes;

    planes[0].setFromCoplanarPoints(vecNear, vecTopLeft, vecTopRight);
    planes[1].setFromCoplanarPoints(vecNear, vecTopRight, vecDownRight);
    planes[2].setFromCoplanarPoints(vecDownRight, vecDownLeft, vecNear);
    planes[3].setFromCoplanarPoints(vecDownLeft, vecTopLeft, vecNear);
    planes[4].setFromCoplanarPoints(vecTopRight, vecDownRight, vecDownLeft);
    planes[5].setFromCoplanarPoints(vectemp3, vectemp2, vectemp1);
    planes[5].normal.multiplyScalar(-1);

  };

  SelectionBox.prototype.searchChildInFrustum = function(frustum, object) {

    if (object.isMesh) {

      if (object.material !== undefined) {

        object.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

        center.copy(object.geometry.boundingSphere.center);

        center.applyMatrix4(object.matrixWorld);

        if (frustum.containsPoint(center)) {

          this.collection.push(object);

        }

      }

    }

    if (object.children.length > 0) {

      for (var x = 0; x < object.children.length; x++) {

        this.searchChildInFrustum(frustum, object.children[x]);

      }

    }

  };

  return SelectionBox;

})();



/**
 * @author HypnosNova / https://www.threejs.org.cn/gallery
 */

THREE.SelectionHelper = (function() {

  function SelectionHelper(selectionBox, renderer, cssClassName) {

    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.classList.add(cssClassName);
    this.element.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

    this.renderer = renderer;

    this.startPoint = new THREE.Vector2();
    this.pointTopLeft = new THREE.Vector2();
    this.pointBottomRight = new THREE.Vector2();

    this.isDown = false;

    this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {

      this.isDown = true;
      this.onSelectStart(event);

    }.bind(this), false);

    this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

      if (this.isDown) {

        this.onSelectMove(event);

      }

    }.bind(this), false);

    this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {

      this.isDown = false;
      this.onSelectOver(event);

    }.bind(this), false);

  }

  SelectionHelper.prototype.onSelectStart = function(event) {

    this.renderer.domElement.parentElement.appendChild(this.element);

    this.element.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
    this.element.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    this.element.style.width = '0px';
    this.element.style.height = '0px';

    this.startPoint.x = event.clientX;
    this.startPoint.y = event.clientY;

  };

  SelectionHelper.prototype.onSelectMove = function(event) {

    this.pointBottomRight.x = Math.max(this.startPoint.x, event.clientX);
    this.pointBottomRight.y = Math.max(this.startPoint.y, event.clientY);
    this.pointTopLeft.x = Math.min(this.startPoint.x, event.clientX);
    this.pointTopLeft.y = Math.min(this.startPoint.y, event.clientY);

    this.element.style.left = this.pointTopLeft.x + 'px';
    this.element.style.top = this.pointTopLeft.y + 'px';
    this.element.style.width = (this.pointBottomRight.x - this.pointTopLeft.x) + 'px';
    this.element.style.height = (this.pointBottomRight.y - this.pointTopLeft.y) + 'px';

  };

  SelectionHelper.prototype.onSelectOver = function() {

    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);

  };

  return SelectionHelper;

})();



var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x505050));

  var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
  light.position.set(0, 500, 2000);
  light.angle = Math.PI / 9;

  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.camera.near = 1000;
  light.shadow.camera.far = 4000;
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;

  scene.add(light);

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 20);

  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: Math.random() * 0xffffff
    }));

    object.position.x = Math.random() * 1600 - 800;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * 900 - 450;
    object.position.z = Math.random() * 900 - 500;

    object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

    object.scale.x = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
    object.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
    object.scale.z = Math.random() * 2 + 1;

    object.castShadow = true;
    object.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(object);

  }

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

var selectionBox = new THREE.SelectionBox(camera, scene);
var helper = new THREE.SelectionHelper(selectionBox, renderer, 'selectBox');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {

  for (var item of selectionBox.collection) {

    item.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

  }

  selectionBox.startPoint.set(
    (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
    0.5);

});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

  if (helper.isDown) {

    for (var i = 0; i < selectionBox.collection.length; i++) {

      selectionBox.collection[i].material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

    }

    selectionBox.endPoint.set(
      (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
      0.5);

    var allSelected = selectionBox.select();

    for (var i = 0; i < allSelected.length; i++) {

      allSelected[i].material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x0000ff);

    }

  }

});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {

  selectionBox.endPoint.set(
    (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
    0.5);

  var allSelected = selectionBox.select();

  for (var i = 0; i < allSelected.length; i++) {

    allSelected[i].material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x0000ff);

  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}
canvas { 
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: #08e;
}

.selectBox {
  border: 1px solid #55aaff;
  background-color: rgba(75, 160, 255, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to zoom in to the selected area? Based on what you're doing, you could try something like this:

```
function zoomToSelection() {
  topLeft = helper.pointTopLeft;
  bottomRight = helper.pointBottomRight;

  // Get the centerpoint of the selection.
  let center = new THREE.Vector2(topLeft.x + (bottomRight.x - topLeft.x) / 2, topLeft.y + (bottomRight.y - topLeft.y) / 2);
  // Get the center position in world space.
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
      (center.x / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
      -(center.y / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
      0.5
  );
  vector.unproject(camera);
  camera.lookAt(vector);
  var movement = vector.clone();

  // Get the ratio between the box size and the window.
  let zoomNeeded = (bottomRight.y - topLeft.y) / window.innerHeight;
  // Get a scalar by which to move the camera in the direction it's looking.
  let distanceToOrigin = camera.position.distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))
  let distance = distanceToOrigin - distanceToOrigin * zoomNeeded;

  movement.sub(camera.position).normalize().multiplyScalar(-zoom);
  var toDirection = camera.position.clone().sub(movement);
  camera.position.set(toDirection.x, toDirection.y, toDirection.z);
}
```

Now just add to your `'mouseup'` event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {

  //...

  zoomToSelection();

});
```

Comment: Can you add that on fiddle in possible @jake

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the value of zoom in below line movement.sub(camera.position).normalize().multiplyScalar(-zoom);